# Creating Vector Map Tiles in ArcGIS Pro with attribution

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, vector-tile-package

I am looking at the ESRI flavour of vector map tiles as a possible replacement for traditional ESRI cache created on ArcGIS Server.

I have created two sample tile packages to test the workflow.  The source data used for one of these was in a postgis database.  The source data used for the other was in an esri fgdb.

Both vector tile packagaes were created in ArcGIS Pro 1.4.  The tiling Scheme used was "VTTS_27700_British_National_Grid" and the Tiling Format was set to "Indexed".

I am able to view both .vtpk files in ArcGIS Pro (v1.4) and in ArcGIS Online.

I have so far been unable to get the attribution to come through when I create the tile packages using the [Create Vector Tile Package](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-vector-tile-package.htm) tool.

According to [this](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/author-a-map-for-vector-tile-creation.htm) ESRI help page I should be able to bring through the attribution, however, I have to specify the fields that I want to bring through.

[image]

I have followed the steps suggested in the article and ticked the "Highlight" box for all the fields I want to carry over to the Vector Map Tiles.

Once the tiles have been created, if I click on a feature I get no attribution & no pop-up.

Has anybody managed to do this?

Comment: Currently vector tile layers in online do not support popups like feature layers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RussRoberts But I am also getting no attribution through in ArcGIS Pro when I open the .vtpk file straight from disc.

Comment: Hi Dan, I've just been playing around with these vector tile packages and wondered if you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: @Hornbydd Kind of!!  The short answer is that we did it using open source software instead as we could create vector tiles that used less memory and the pop-ups just worked. I think we used MapBox, but I could be wrong!!  However, I did speak to Ben Flanagan at ESRI UK (cartography wiz) and he confirmed that the only way to see the attribution was by accessing it through the sdk's / api's.  Following the workflow I have stated above exposes the attribution which can then be accessed with code.  However, this was 2 years ago and so it could have changed.  Let me know how you get on!